# filebeat logs to kafka to clickhouse not persisiting using docker-compose

Tags: docker, clickhouse, filebeat

Im trying to insert the file beat collected logs to Kafka and Kafka will store the logs in Clickhouse, File beat to Kafka logs are sending but Kafka is unable to send/store logs to Clickhouse. I don't see any weird logs while checking the container. Please guide me did i do something wrong here.

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.0.1
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/var/log/"
      - "./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
    container_name: filebeat
    networks:
      - filebeat-net
    depends_on:
      - kafka
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.7
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper-data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - filebeat-net
    container_name: zookeeper
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - '29092:29092'
    volumes:
      - "kafka-data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - "HOSTNAME_COMMAND=docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      - "KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT"
      - "ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes"
      - "KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181"
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - "KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT"
      - "KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:29092"
      - "KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092"
      - "KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - filebeat-net  
    container_name: kafka

  clickhouse-server:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:22.5.1
    container_name: clickhouse-server
    hostname: clickhouse-server
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - './init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sql'
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - filebeat-net


networks:
  filebeat-net:
    name: filebeat-net
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
    name: zookeeper-data
    driver: local
  kafka-data:
    name: kafka-data
    driver: local
```

> filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  paths:
  - /var/log/*.log

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["kafka:9092"]
  topic: hello-messages
```

> init.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mylogger (  
     id String, 
          event_time DateTime64(6),  
            details_json String)  
            ENGINE  = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(event_time) ORDER BY (id, event_time) SETTINGS index_granularity=8192;

CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS 
mylogger_kafka ( payload String ) ENGINE = Kafka('kafka:9092', 'hello-messages', 'KAFKA2CH_click', 'JSONAsString');   


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mylogger_kafka_consumer TO mylogger AS 
SELECT JSONExtractString(payload, 'payload', 'after', 'id')    as id, 
 toDateTime64(JSONExtractString(payload, 'payload', 'after', 'event_time'), 3, 'Asia/Jerusalem') as event_time, 
 JSONExtractString(payload, 'payload', 'after', 'details_json')    as details_json 
 FROM mylogger_kafka;
```

Comment: There's at least one typo above, since filebeat is going to the `hello-message-1` topic and the topic list for the Kafka engine is just `hello-messages`

Comment: sorry it's  a typo in stackoverflow, topic is correct